# Creating API with Symfony2

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1

I have a question about API,then how to create an API using Symfony2 and what bundles I can use to help to create it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create a REST API (a service based API), [here](http://williamdurand.fr/2012/08/02/rest-apis-with-symfony2-the-right-way/) is a step by step tutorial that could help you doing it the right way > [REST APIs with Symfony2](http://williamdurand.fr/2012/08/02/rest-apis-with-symfony2-the-right-way/)

Also, take a look at the [FOSRestBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle)

Comment: Ok Ahmed,I saw this link before but thank you,u know I worked at Smile too in morocco...

Comment: Ah great! I'm delighted to meet you. But just tell me what your API is supposed to do? Can you just give more details :)

Comment: Nothing yet maybe in a few days I will have a freelance mission when I will use an API with Symfony2,maybe we can talk more on Gmail if you don't mind :)

Comment: Ok, right :) here's my gmail address > ahmed.siouani@gmail.com
. The given tutorial and bundle could really be a good start for you. I also advice you to read [this](http://mattgemmell.com/2012/05/24/api-design/) article on [API Design](http://mattgemmell.com/2012/05/24/api-design/)

Comment: Ok thank you again it's ineteresting,also I invited you for chatting :)